# mysql create table FOREIGN key syntax

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, primary-key

1. I'm trying to create two tables 'ROOMS' and 'Has'
2. ROOM contains PRIMARY KEY 'type'
3. Has contains FOREIGN KEY `room-type' <---here is the problem

my sql code will not accept line 28

```
 FOREIGN KEY(`room-type`) REFERENCES ROOM(type)
```

[image]

[image]

I'm completely lost as to why this won't work. It seems simple enough. Any help would me greatly appreciated.  I'm absolutely stumped.

Answer (score 0):

DOH!   ENUM != VARCHAR(50)  ..lol saw it when i posted the smaller section of code

Answer (score 0):

Foreign keys can only reference a column of exactly the same data type.

Your room-type column is varchar(50) The type column it references is ENUM, which is stored internally like an int.

Exceptions:

A VARCHAR(50) can reference a string of a different length, like VARCHAR(100) or VARCHAR(25) or others. But differences in character set would count as different data types.

Integer "size" is meaningless, so INT(11) can reference INT(18). Both are 32-bit integers regardless of the size argument. But an INT cannot reference an INT UNSIGNED or a BIGINT or others.